# Concatenate slices from pointer passed as interface

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, slice

I'm working on a client for a specific API, and I built several structures (one for each route).
The API works with pages so I have getters returning slices of a struct. This is done passing through a common function that takes an interface supposed to be a pointer to a slice of the wanted structure so I can use `Unmarshal` from the `json` package.

The problem I'm facing is that I would like to get all the pages in a single request, but in order to do that I would need to concatenate several slices.

I tried to do this using `reflect` but I can only manage to create a new slice without actually altering the value that my interface is pointing to.

Here's a part of my code:

```
func concatenateSlice(dst, src interface{})(){
    dstValue := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    srcValue := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    if srcValue.Type() != dstValue.Type(){
        return
    }
    switch srcValue.Kind(){
    case reflect.Ptr, reflect.Slice:
        dstValuePoint := reflect.Indirect(dstValue)
        srcValuePoint := reflect.Indirect(srcValue)
        reflect.Copy(dstValuePoint, reflect.AppendSlice(dstValuePoint, srcValuePoint))
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for the sloppy post, this is my first time on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use [`reflect.Copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Copy) to copy the result slice (after append), as destination will not have enough space. [`reflect.AppendSlice()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#AppendSlice) will not change the slice pointed by `dst`, it will allocate a new one if needed, and it returns the new slice (more precisely the [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) holding it).

What you should do is set the slice returned by `reflect.AppendSlice()` to the value pointed by `dst`, simply using the [`Value.Set()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Set) method. One thing to note is that you are not setting a slice pointer but a slice, so first call e.g. [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) before calling `Set()`.

See this example:

```
func concatenateSlice(dst, src interface{}) {
    dv := reflect.ValueOf(dst)
    sv := reflect.ValueOf(src)
    if dv.Type() != sv.Type() {
        return
    }

    dv2 := reflect.AppendSlice(dv.Elem(), sv.Elem())
    dv.Elem().Set(dv2)
}
```

Testing it:

```
dst := []int{1, 2}
src := []int{3, 4}

concatenateSlice(&dst, &src)

fmt.Println(dst)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/V-d9F6zisbD)):

```
[1 2 3 4]
```

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem and helped me understand the `reflect` pkg better !